# Does Keyboard Listener not listen keyEvents of Mobile Virtual Keyboard?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyevent

When I open same application that is running on web I receives input key events from physical keyboard but when I run the same application on mobile then there is no keyboard open for taking input so that's why this is not generating key events? Is there any possibility to listen mobile keyboard event?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a RawKeyboardListener widget to listen to key presses, then it won't work for mobile, because as the name suggests, it listens to raw keybaord (hardware keyboard, not virtual). You can instead make use of this code (do import 'dart:ui' for accessing the window.onKeyData function, and then set it as you want):

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    window.onKeyData = (KeyData keyData) {
      // it can be any key you want, I'm using arrowUp here just as an example.

      if (keyData.logical == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp.keyId) {
        // execute your method here for the pressed key
        return true;
      }

      // The keyData will be given to other widgets such as textfields by flutter if you return false. Return false if your method is not executed till now, that is, when none of your conditions matches. I've saw this approach somewhere else on stackoverflow too, so don't have much idea about it either, but yeah, this is also a way that you can listen to keyboard presses.
      return false;
    };
  }
```

There are some other options/packages too, you can check them out on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev). A default alternative to RawKeyboardListener is just KeyboardListener. Also keep in mind to always wrap your whole Scaffold widget inside listeners widgets like the above (to get events of everything that falls under your Scaffold), otherwise it won't function as desired sometimes.

Comment: Since version 3.10.0, the window singleton is deprecated, now you can use `PlatformDispatcher.instance.onKeyData`